# Environment variable not exported

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have set a variable MY_HOME and I have also exported it. So exporting it should make it visible to all child processes.

I have the following script.

```
echo "MY_HOME:" $MY_HOME
if [ "$MY_HOME" = "" ];
then
    echo "ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE NOT SET"
    echo "READ THE DOCUMENTATION FOR THE ERROR"
    exit 0 
fi
```

This script is invoked from the shell in which I exported the MY_HOME variable. But it seems that MY_HOME is not initialized. Why is it so?

My learning is that, exporting should make the variable visible to child processes. And ./script spawns a subshell which is a child  of current shell.

Am I missing something? Why is this not working for me?

Comment: Try saying `echo $MY_HOME` from the command line.  What does it say?

Comment: @devnull It displays the contents if I echo from the command line. It is really weird. First of all, is my understanding of the export and child processes, as mentioned above in the question, correct??

Comment: @devnull Forgot to mention that, I run the script with sudo permission. The sudo command would produce a sub shell and executing a script in it would create a sub-sub-shell. But in that case too, all the two shell would receive the variable from its ancestor shell, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820978/environment-variable-not-exported?noredirect=1#comment27761524_18820978) says that you're executing the script using `sudo`.

Specify the `-E` option to `sudo` while executing the script.

```
   -E          The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the
               security policy that the user wishes to preserve their
               existing environment variables.  The security policy may
               return an error if the -E option is specified and the user
               does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```